# jQuery: сделать несколько событий на различные классы

Tags: html, jquery, css

[![при клике на .Card или .Link должен меняться фон (#e52e7a) у .Card, и .Card-ItemWeight плюс у .Promotion должен меняться текст плюс у Card-Heading должен меняться цвет текста. Вопрос: как это все сделать через jQuery? И как потом по клику по карточке отменить селект.

```js
$('.Card').on('click', function() {
 
 $(this).css('background-color', '#e52e7a');

});
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ContentContainer {
 margin: auto;
 width: 1280px;
 height: 680px;
 vertical-align: top;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.PageBackground {
 background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%), url(../img/background.png);
 background-color: #fff;
}
.Heading {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 36px;
 font: 100 36px 'Exo 2.0 Thin', sans-serif;
 color: #fff; 
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
 text-align: center;
}
.Container {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 320px;
 height: auto;
 margin-top: 23px;
 margin-left: 80px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 vertical-align: top;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.Card {
 margin: 0;
 width: 320px;
 height: 480px;
 background-color: #2ea8e6;
 border-radius: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 10%);
 clip-path:         polygon(15% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 10%);
}


.Card::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 4px;
 left: 4px;
 width: 312px;
 height: 472px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 10%);
 clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 10%);
 z-index: 1;

}
.Card:hover, .Card:hover .Card-ItemWeight {
 background-color: #e52e7a;
}

.Card-Heading {
 position: relative;
 font: 16px 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 color: #666666;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 21px 0 0 51px; 
 z-index: 2;
 
}
.Card-Title {
 position: relative;
 font: 700 48px 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 color: #000;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 6px 0 0 48px; 
 z-index: 3;
}
.Card-SubTitle {
 position: relative;
 font: 700 24px 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 color: #000;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 51px; 
 z-index: 4;
}
.Card-Details {
 position: relative;
 font: 400 14px/16px 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 color: #666666;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 15px 0 0 51px;
 z-index: 5;
 
}
.Card-Details_font_bold {
 font-weight: 700;
}
.Card-Image {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 4px;
 left: 4px;
 z-index: 6;
 
}
.Card-ItemWeight {
 position: absolute;
 right: 16px;
 bottom: 16px;
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 background-color: #2ea8e6;
 border-radius: 50%;
 z-index: 7;
}



.Card-ItemWeightText {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 24px; 
 text-align: center;
 font: 400 42px/22px 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
}
.Card-ItemWeightText_font_s {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 30px;
 font-size: 21px;
}
.Promotion {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 14px;
 font: 13px 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 color:#fff;
 text-align: center;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
.Link {
 font: 700 13px 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 color: #22a7e9;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: 1px dashed;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="ContentContainer PageBackground">
   <h1 class="Heading">Ты сегодня покормил кота?</h1>
   <div class="Container">
    <div class="Card">
     <p class="Card-Heading">Сказочное заморское яство</p>
     <h2 class="Card-Title">Нямушка</h2>
     <h3 class="Card-SubTitle">с фуа-гра</h3>
     <p class="Card-Details"><span class="Card-Details_font_bold">10</span> порций <br> мышь в подарок</p>
     <img class="Card-Image" src="img/cat.png" width="314" height="272" alt="cat"> 
     <div class="Card-ItemWeight">
      <p class="Card-ItemWeightText">0,5<br>
       <span class="Card-ItemWeightText_font_s">кг</span>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <p class="Promotion Promotion-TextOne">Чего сидишь? Порадуй котэ, <a class="Link" href="#">купи.</a></p>
   </div>

   <div class="Container">
    <div class="Card">
     <p class="Card-Heading">Сказочное заморское яство</p>
     <h2 class="Card-Title">Нямушка</h2>
     <h3 class="Card-SubTitle">с рыбой</h3>
     <p class="Card-Details"><span class="Card-Details_font_bold">40</span> порций <br> <span class="Card-Details_font_bold">2</span> мыши в подарок</p>
     <img class="Card-Image" src="img/cat.png" width="314" height="272" alt="cat">
     <div class="Card-ItemWeight">
      <p class="Card-ItemWeightText">2<br>
       <span class="Card-ItemWeightText_font_s">кг</span>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <p class="Promotion Promotion-TextTwo">Чего сидишь? Порадуй котэ, <a class="Link" href="#">купи.</a></p>
   </div>

   <div class="Container">
    <div class="Card">
     <p class="Card-Heading">Сказочное заморское яство</p>
     <h2 class="Card-Title">Нямушка</h2>
     <h3 class="Card-SubTitle">с курой</h3>
     <p class="Card-Details"><span class="Card-Details_font_bold">100</span> порций <br> <span class="Card-Details_font_bold">5</span> мышей в подарок <br> заказчик доволен</p>
     <img class="Card-Image" src="img/cat.png" width="314" height="272" alt="cat">
     <div class="Card-ItemWeight">
      <p class="Card-ItemWeightText">5<br>
       <span class="Card-ItemWeightText_font_s">кг</span>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <p class="Promotion Promotion-TextThree">Чего сидишь? Порадуй котэ, <a class="Link" href="#">купи.</a></p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js" defer></script>
  
 </body>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhIhg.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhIhg.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.Card').on('click', function() {
 
 $(this).toggleClass("Card_active");

});
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ContentContainer {
 margin: auto;
 width: 1280px;
 height: 680px;
 vertical-align: top;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.PageBackground {
 background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%), url(../img/background.png);
 background-color: #fff;
}
.Heading {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 36px;
 font: 100 36px 'Exo 2.0 Thin', sans-serif;
 color: #fff; 
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
 text-align: center;
}
.Container {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 320px;
 height: auto;
 margin-top: 23px;
 margin-left: 80px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 vertical-align: top;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.Card {
 margin: 0;
 width: 320px;
 height: 480px;
 background-color: #2ea8e6;
 border-radius: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 10%);
 clip-path:         polygon(15% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 10%);
}


.Card::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 4px;
 left: 4px;
 width: 312px;
 height: 472px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 10%);
 clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 10%);
 z-index: 1;

}

.Card_active {
  background-color:  #e52e7a;
}

.Card-Heading {
 position: relative;
 font: 16px 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 color: #666666;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 21px 0 0 51px; 
 z-index: 2;
}

.Card_active .Card-Heading {
  color:  #e52e7a;
}




.Card-Title {
 position: relative;
 font: 700 48px 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 color: #000;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 6px 0 0 48px; 
 z-index: 3;
}
.Card-SubTitle {
 position: relative;
 font: 700 24px 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 color: #000;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 51px; 
 z-index: 4;
}
.Card-Details {
 position: relative;
 font: 400 14px/16px 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 color: #666666;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 15px 0 0 51px;
 z-index: 5;
 
}
.Card-Details_font_bold {
 font-weight: 700;
}
.Card-Image {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 4px;
 left: 4px;
 z-index: 6;
 
}
.Card-ItemWeight {
 position: absolute;
 right: 16px;
 bottom: 16px;
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 background-color: #2ea8e6;
 border-radius: 50%;
 z-index: 7;
}

.Card_active .Card-ItemWeight {
  background-color:  #e52e7a;
}



.Card-ItemWeightText {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 24px; 
 text-align: center;
 font: 400 42px/22px 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
}
.Card-ItemWeightText_font_s {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 30px;
 font-size: 21px;
}
.Promotion {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 14px;
 font: 13px 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 color:#fff;
 text-align: center;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

.Promotion .Promotion_second {
  display: none;
}

.Card_active + .Promotion .Promotion_first {
  display: none;
}

.Card_active + .Promotion .Promotion_second {
  display: inline-block;
}

.Link {
 font: 700 13px 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 color: #22a7e9;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: 1px dashed;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="ContentContainer PageBackground">
   <h1 class="Heading">Ты сегодня покормил кота?</h1>
   <div class="Container">
    <div class="Card">
     <p class="Card-Heading">Сказочное заморское яство</p>
     <h2 class="Card-Title">Нямушка</h2>
     <h3 class="Card-SubTitle">с фуа-гра</h3>
     <p class="Card-Details"><span class="Card-Details_font_bold">10</span> порций <br> мышь в подарок</p>
     <img class="Card-Image" src="img/cat.png" width="314" height="272" alt="cat"> 
     <div class="Card-ItemWeight">
      <p class="Card-ItemWeightText">0,5<br>
       <span class="Card-ItemWeightText_font_s">кг</span>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <p class="Promotion Promotion-TextOne"> 
        <span class="Promotion_first">Чего сидишь? Порадуй котэ, <a class="Link" href="#">купи.</a></span>
        <span class="Promotion_second">Не покупай, <a class="Link" href="#">ок?</a></span>
        </p>
   </div>

   <div class="Container">
    <div class="Card">
     <p class="Card-Heading">Сказочное заморское яство</p>
     <h2 class="Card-Title">Нямушка</h2>
     <h3 class="Card-SubTitle">с рыбой</h3>
     <p class="Card-Details"><span class="Card-Details_font_bold">40</span> порций <br> <span class="Card-Details_font_bold">2</span> мыши в подарок</p>
     <img class="Card-Image" src="img/cat.png" width="314" height="272" alt="cat">
     <div class="Card-ItemWeight">
      <p class="Card-ItemWeightText">2<br>
       <span class="Card-ItemWeightText_font_s">кг</span>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <p class="Promotion Promotion-TextOne"> 
        <span class="Promotion_first">Чего сидишь? Порадуй котэ, <a class="Link" href="#">купи.</a></span>
        <span class="Promotion_second">Не покупай, <a class="Link" href="#">ок?</a></span>
        </p>
   </div>

   <div class="Container">
    <div class="Card">
     <p class="Card-Heading">Сказочное заморское яство</p>
     <h2 class="Card-Title">Нямушка</h2>
     <h3 class="Card-SubTitle">с курой</h3>
     <p class="Card-Details"><span class="Card-Details_font_bold">100</span> порций <br> <span class="Card-Details_font_bold">5</span> мышей в подарок <br> заказчик доволен</p>
     <img class="Card-Image" src="img/cat.png" width="314" height="272" alt="cat">
     <div class="Card-ItemWeight">
      <p class="Card-ItemWeightText">5<br>
       <span class="Card-ItemWeightText_font_s">кг</span>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <p class="Promotion Promotion-TextOne"> 
        <span class="Promotion_first">Чего сидишь? Порадуй котэ, <a class="Link" href="#">купи.</a></span>
        <span class="Promotion_second">Не покупай, <a class="Link" href="#">ок?</a></span>
        </p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js" defer></script>
  
 </body>
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Но есть проблема: класс да, меняется, но стили не срабатывают почему то...не пойму пока

Comment: все заработало! Спасибо.